# 5702 : The SQL Server is terminating this process because the database view

Tags: sap-iq

after modifying the view as below, if use the view in the select statements by the application(as below query), then we are getting

> DB error 5702: The SQL Server is terminating this process.

Here's the query

```
select *
from view1 v1,
view2 v2
where v1.column in(select M_FLOW_ID from VW_NETPAY_UNDO)
```

is the issue because more number of view in sql statements ?

Answer (score 1):

Most provably is that your query is runing for a long long time and sybase decided to stop the process,  root of the problem ist that  you have a cross join between the 2 Views.
You should match the 2 views,(on View1.columnA= View2.columnA)

```
    select *
     from view1 v1,
     view2 v2 on V1.id = V2.id  -- id like common value column
      where v1.column in(select colum1 from table1)
```

.If you don´t do that you have a cartesian products between the 2 Views and then the resuld wouldnt arrise.

Best Regards, 
Enrique